# Android getting image size from non-activity class

Tags: android, screen

I need to get my screens dimensions in order to make my application work. to do that, i have created 2 functions in my main activity and im calling them via an objects from a non-Activity class.

For some reason, it keeps crashing. Why cant i call these functions? How do i fix it?

Code of main activity:

```
    public int getWidth(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int height = display.getHeight(); 
    return height;
}
```

Code of the non-activity (calling part):

```
    main Main = new main();
private int height = Main.getHeight();
private int width = Main.getWidth();
```

Please note i am aware those methods are deprecated, but i cant use the getSize(point); method because im developing for minimum API level 7.

Comment: Post your stack trace from your crash.

Comment: Nothing to show, it crashes on the first line of the getHeight(); function since that is the first one called.

Comment: can't we pass context in constructor of non-Activity class ?

Comment: not sure what do you mean.. can you post an example?

Comment: It's not an easier approach to calculate it in your activity and just pass the values to your class? A static variable for example?

Comment: can't do that, because display cant be static. if im wrong, please post a code example.

Comment: @arielschon12 There's pretty much always something to show. The specific exception type is relevant.

Comment: Dont have any exceptions. in LogCat i get a runtime error in the first line of the getHeight(); function, thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just create an `Activity` with its constructor and expect it to be properly initialized. That's not how it works. If you just call with the constructor, it won't have its context which it needs to get system services. You need to get this info from a real instance of an activity then pass it to the objects that need this data. Without more info/code it's not really practical to give more detail than that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class `Constants` containing statics fields that you initialize in the `onCreate` of your `Activity` like :

```
public class Constants
{
    public static int DEVICE_WIDTH;
    public static int DEVICE_HEIGHT;
}
```

Activity

```
onCreate(...)
{
    ...
    Constants.DEVICE_WIDTH  = this.getWidth();
    Constants.DEVICE_HEIGHT = this.getHeight();
}
```

And when you need those values, call it with :

```
int deviceWidth = Constants.DEVICE_WIDTH;
```